# Is there a way to get URL used to launch the app in the code for "Flutter web" app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When building a web app using Dart & Flutter web, can we somehow get the URL used to launch the web app in Dart code? I need to build a web app for a tool that the user will locally deploy on one of his machines and then launch from browser. I need to be able to get the IP address/host name of the server in the web app and then do further gRPC/REST calls.

Comment: Does `window.location` from dart HTML do what you had in mind?

Comment: See the properties available on `window.location` [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-html/Location-class.html). `href` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. yes, this is what I was looking for. I did not even come across that there is a dart:html package until I tried tagging the question. your answer then gave me the complete picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use something like the following untested example:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

...
// Use whichever of the following you need:
final url = html.window.location.href;
final hostname = html.window.location.hostname; // you probably need this one
```